# Why Assembly.Load loads wrong assembly version?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

Code first:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  
                                   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
Console.WriteLine(assembly.FullName);
```

and the result is:

> mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Why?

Comment: I suspect you can't since mscorlib is loaded during application initialization. Having multiple version of mscorlib in the same appdomain would be a weird situation.

Comment: You would need to set useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy to true if you want to load older assemblies. Here is something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959843/how-can-i-load-an-older-version-of-a-net-assembly